# Firebase Email and Password Registration on Flutter - Unable to resolve host

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have been having some problems with `Firebase Auth` on using the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method on Flutter. The `signInAnonymously` method works fine, but the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method gives me the following error:

```
 [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you're having this problem, try rebooting your virtual device in the AVD Manager (Cold Reboot). It worked for me; turns out it was a connection problem.